# Função para printar diretório em uma Label Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Criei uma função que abre um arquivo com o Tkinter + filedialog, até ai tudo certo.

Porém preciso printar o diretório do arquivo selecionado em uma Label.

Segue função:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd

def browse_button2():
    df2 = pd.read_csv(filedialog.askopenfile()) #aqui o botão seleciona o arquivo
    lb2["text"] = filedialog.askopenfilename() #aqui estou tentando definir que o label receba em sua propriedade "text" como valor a caminho do arquivo selecionado, Exemplo "C:\documentos\texte.csv"
    return df2

lb2 = Label(root, font=( 'arial', 10), bd=1, width=43, height=1, relief=RIDGE, borderwidth=1)
lb2.grid(row=2, column=0)
lb2.configure(background='#FFFFFF')
lb2.place(x=48, y=136)
```

[image: Segue Imagem do sistema]

Answer (score 1):

Para inserir um texto no `Label` use o método `config` e passe o diretório obtido como argumento para o parâmetro `text`. O objeto Label funciona também como um dicionário, logo você também pode definir a chave `text` do objeto com o diretório: Exemplo:

```
label.config(text=path)
label["text"] = path
```

O seu programa está abrindo duas vezes a caixa de diálogo porque você está chamando `askopenfile()` na primeira linha da função e depois você está chamando `askopenfilename()` na terceira linha.

Talvez o que você queira é usar o diretório do arquivo selecionado no `filedialog.askopenfile()` para inserir no Label. Para isso, basta usar o atributo `name` para pegar o diretório do arquivo:

```
def browse_button2():
    file = filedialog.askopenfile() # Recebo o arquivo selecionado
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file)
    lb2["text"] = file.name # Estou passando o diretório do arquivo selecionado
    return df2
```

Comment: para printar o diretório usei o seguinte   lb2["text"] = filedialog.askopenfilename()                  ele da certo ele printa o diretório do arquivo, porem ele abre 2x a caixa de dialogo para selecionar um arquivo

Comment: entendi,  vou tentar explicar de uma forma melhor. para abrir o arquivo estou utilizando o askopenfile(), que me abre uma janela para escolher o arquivo. eu não estou discrevendo no código um caminho fixo para escolher o arquivo. quando portanto quando utilizo o comando da forma que vc me mandou ele printa o camino da função "Path" e nao do caminho do arquvo que selecionei

Comment: Acho que entendi o que você quer então, vou editar a resposta. Por favor veja se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Muito bom, é isso mesmo, muito obrigad, sou novo com programação, isso é bem basico mas pra quem ta comesando as vezes enrroca em coisas bobas